# Drupal Views: Handle title field links differently depending on content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, hyperlink, drupal-views

I have a view that pulls in the titles from 3 different content types. One of these content types has a title that should link to an external website, the other 2 types have titles that link to nodes within the Drupal site. Is there a way I can set the Title field to handle links differently depending on what content type the title is from?

**Answered thanks to Vlad below!! :)**

This is the working code we are using in the `views-view-fields--news--block.tpl.php` template..

```
<?php if ($fields['type']->content == 'Event'): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $fields['path']->content; ?>"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($fields['type']->content == 'PATF News'): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $fields['path']->content; ?>"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($fields['type']->content == 'News Link'): ?>
//This link goes to _blank
 <a href="<?php print $fields['field_link']->content; ?>" target="_blank"><?php print $fields['title']->content; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Which version of Drupal do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Drupal 6**

1. In your view settings, add `Node: Type` to `Fields`
2. In `Basic settings` group click `Theme: Information` and click `Row style output`
3. Copy all content from `Row style output` into your theme file (should be named something like `views-view-fields--viewsname.tpl.php` or `views-view-fields--viewsname--viewsnamw.tpl.php`) in your theme folder.
4. Modify output where you should check content type and make different output.

**Drupal 7**

It's pretty similar with difference that you can find `Theme: Information` in group `Advanced` and you have to add `Content: Type` in your `Fields` group.

In your `views-view-fields--xxx--xxx.tpl.php` file write something like:

```
if ($fields['type']->content == 'Page') {
  // print title linking to node
  print $fields['title']->content;
}
if ($fields['type']->content == 'News') {
  // print title linking to other website
  print 'http://example.com/'. $fields['title']->content;
}
```

**Improved code**

```
$link = $fields['path']->content;
$title = $fields['title']->content;
$options = array();

if ($fields['type']->content == 'News Link') {
  $link = $fields['field_link']->content;
  $options['attributes']['target'] = '_blank';
}

print l($title, $link, $options);
```

Comment: How would I check for the content type? If its any help, my view is a block.

Comment: Gave your suggestion a shot. Seems like something is wrong with the if statement though. Maybe because we are filtering by content type. The content type isn't a field.

Comment: I've wrote that you have to add it into your fields of your view. Give more details about your view settings, and I'll give more detailed answer.

Comment: I've added an export of the view to my post. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to add `Content: Type` in your `Fields` group. After that, `$fields['type']->content` will be available in your `.tpl.php` file.

Comment: Ok we seem to be pretty close now. Now the issue is I don't know how to link a title to its node within Drupal. We had to turn off the "link title to its node" in the view. See my updated question above to see the code we have in our field template.

Comment: What your `alias` and `field_link` return?

Comment: We got it now, working code is posted above. Thank you so much Vlad!!

Answer (score -1):

I've done this before with the following steps:

1. Include fields for **Content Title**, **Content Link**, and your **external
   Link**.
2. Hide Content Title and Content Link from view.
3. **Rewrite results** for Content Link should be set to the token for
   Content Title (both still hidden).
4. **No results behavior** for you external link field should be set to the
   token for Content Link.

This displays the external link whenever it's present, and will fall back to a the title linked to the original piece of content whenever it's not.